# Flutter Stacked Widgets see-through from top widget to bottom widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
Stack(
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       children: [
         ContainerA(),
         ContainerB(),
         ContainerC(),
       ],
     );
```

[image]
Container A contains the background gradient. Container B is a different gradient. On Container C I want to have it see-through container B and render Container A's gradient, exactly behind itself (For eg, If Container C is at a corner it should render the gradient behind that spot on Container A).

I am not talking about glass morphism, we have a lot of those on pub.dev.

How should I approach this from scratch?

Comment: I suspect it'll be something with an AutomaticNotchedShape, but I don't have time right now to flesh that out.

Comment: Why not display the text on Container C itself? i don't think seeing though a widget which isn't transparent could be possible

Comment: I am not able to see how AutomativNotchedShape could help. @RandalSchwartz

Comment: What about the gradient on Container A ?  @SankethB.K

Answer (score 0):

I think [flutter_mask_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mask_view) or [widget_mask](https://pub.dev/packages/widget_mask) solves the problem, maybe with some customizationit will be perfect.

Comment: widget_mask code uses Save Layer for painting each widget in its separate layer. The widget works for Text Widgets only, but I think I have a starting point for my implementation.